# Multiplication in the Galois field GF(3^3)

Tags: finite-fields, cryptography

I am trying to compute $x^3$ in the Galois field $\text{GF}(3^3)$ using the irreducible polynomial $f(x) = x^3 + 2x^2 + 1$.

From the expression $x^3 = f(x) + (2x^2 +1)$ I proceed to take the modulus of $f(x)$
which gives me the wrong result $x^3 \equiv 2 x^2 + 1 \bmod f(x)$.

Sage gives me the correct answer:

```
F.<y> = GF(3)[]
K.<z> = GF(3**3, name='z', modulus=y^3 + 2*y^2 + 1)
z^3             
z^2 + 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it's not as simple as a wrong sign, is it? $x^3=f(x)-(2x^2+1)$ …

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you!

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: Maybe you should write this as an answer?

Comment: @Thomas: Nah, I'll just upvote the who did instead. It's far easier. There, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^3 + 2x^2 + 1 \equiv 0$, so $x^3 \equiv -(2x^2 + 1) = -2x^2 - 1 \equiv x^2 + 2$, as coefficients are mod 3.

So your sign was off, as stated in the comments.